# CPack: How to specify different package versions for components?

Tags: cmake, packaging, cpack

I have a CMake project to build multiple shared libraries and tools, most of these under subdirectories:

```
add_directory(libFirst)
add_directory(libSecond)
add_directory(myTool)
# etc...
```

The `install(TARGET "someTarget" COMPONENT "someTarget" ...)` rules are in the respective `subdirectory/CMakeLists.txt` files.

I would like to generate Debian packages for all of these using a `make package` command from the build directory. I have `CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL` set to `ON`.

The problem I'm facing, is that not all of the targets have the same `VERSION` and/or `SOVERSION`. For example, `libFirst` is at version 1.0.0.0 and `libSecond` is version 4.3.0.0. This means that the generated packages should also have different version, but the only way I've found to specify the version is to specify the `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR`,  `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR` and `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH` variables (and perhaps the internal `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION` variable), which set the version for **all** generated packages.

Is there a way to set package versions per-component, for example by setting some variables similarly to the other `CPACK_COMPONENT_<COMPONENT>_*` or `CPACK_DEBIAN_<COMPONENT>_*` variables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at the moment but I have created a merge-request (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2305) which provides this functionality.

I hope it will get approved but in the meantime you can locally change your CPackDeb.cmake as shown in this diff: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2305/diffs. The default location of that file is in /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake.